# Changing a Regular Outlet with Two Neutrals and One Hot to a GFCI Outlet (no ground existing)

Tags: gfci

So I bought a GFCI outlet to changeout a regular outlet and when I pulled the regular, it had white wires/neutrals on both left side screw connections and one black on the top right connection.  I do not know what I should do for the GFCI outlet as the top two connections are line and bottom two are load, so I cannot hook up three wires (not even sure why a regular outlet would have two neutrals and one hot).  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Also next to the outlet is an existing switch in the same larger outlet box.  I do not know if that would have anything to do with it, not sure why, but that is the situation.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is the original outlet a three-prong? Is there a ground wire present in the box?

Comment: Can you shoot us a photo of what's going on in the back of the box? Are any tabs broken off on the outlet?   We don't care about left side right side, but we do care about silver screws vs brass....

Comment: Can you post photos of what's going on here?

Comment: Is there a pigtailed hot in the box? 2 Hots connected then just the 1 wire connecting to the outlet.

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of GFCIs is, if you don't *really* know how LOAD works, don't use it.

On a plain receptacle, the extra screws are spare terminals (unless the tab(s) are broken, then different deal).  Not on a GFCI.

This sounds like a picture postcard case of "don't use LOAD". (I know exactly what it does and I wouldn't use it either).   Either pigtail the 2 wires to the 1 `LINE` screw, or most GFCIs provide a method for back-wiring 2 wires onto 1 screw, in which you insert the back-wire and tighten the screw (*a lot*) to clamp them.